# Which country's laws apply to a company in country A hiring remote workers in country B?

Tags: employment, international

If a company in a country A does remote hiring of employees in a country B, laws of which of these two countries have to be considered?

context: in some countries hiring employees has very strict laws (gender, race discrimination e.g.), while in some countries there are no laws for admission interviews and a company can choose whoever they prefer to employ.

Thank you.

Comment: For the special case where A and B aer EU members, see https://www.europarl.europa.eu/workingpapers/soci/w16/summary_en.htm

Answer (score 2):

### The laws of both countries apply

Comment: But what if they are different? E.g. in country A there are laws for race discrimination and in country B a company can choose anyone they want. The laws are contradictory, how can they be combined to be applied both?

Comment: @JaneB. You ask your lawyer. In any event, those laws aren’t contradictory, if B’s laws say you *must* discriminate they are but not if they don’t say anything.

Comment: @JaneB. If the laws for some specific situation contradict each other then you can't hire a recome worker for this specific situation.

Comment: The "must discriminate" part sounds unbelievable, but some countries do in fact require gender discrimination (specifically, to favor women for certain desirable functions).

Comment: @MSalters there are plenty of places both now and in the past that have “must discriminate” laws. Nazi Germany for example. More broadly, working visas on foreigners are a “must discriminate” law.

Comment: Sources? Details? Or is this your own personal opinion?

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry There's no meta-law that governs how law functions between jurisdictions, so it can't be more than an empirical observation. ([The same thing said by someone else.](/posts/39381)) There are plenty of firms specialising in international employment law, which wouldn't be a thing if only the law where a company's headquartered would apply.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 still, there must be sources, even from few places, or not definitive. Checking random answers now in the first page, some have links and other have details, not just one line opinion. Anyway, that's not my site, and I'm not going to try and change anything, just gave my view on this.

Comment: Btw the link in my previous comment should be [correct link](/posts/comments/39381).